# Encoding an URL sent to a server (not in query)

Tags: java, apache

I need to be testing my server for several URLs daily since these URLs are updated by my users - and this will be dine in Java. However, these URLs contains strange characters (like the german umlaut). Basicly what I am doing is:

```
for every URL in the list to check
  URL u = new URL(the_url);
  u.openConnection(..);
  // read the content and handle it
```

Now, what Ive found is that `org.apache.commons.codec.net.URLCodec` is fine for encoding string to paste into the QueryString, it is not as suitable to encode strange URLs into their hex counterparts. Here are some examples of URLs:

- http:// www.example com/u/überraum-03/
- http:// www.example com/u/são-paulo-dude/
- http:// www.example com/u/håkon-hellström/

The desired result for the first would be;

- http:// www.example com/u/%c3%9berraum-03/

Are there any library in the Apache Commons or java itself, to convert special character in the ACTUAL url (not querystring - and therefore not replace the same kind of characters) ?

Thank you for your time.

**Edited**
Firefox translates "yr.no/place/Norway/Nordland/Moskenes/Å/data.html"; into "yr.no/place/Norway/Nordland/Moskenes/%C3%85/data.html" (try this by entering the first URL, press enter, then copy the url into a document). It is this effect that I am looking for - since this is the actual translation. What is most likely happening is either FF knows Å is a bad thing, it tries multiple versions or it accepts the servers "Location" header; either way - there is a tranformation from "Å" to "%C3%85" on only a subset of the URL. This is the function we need.

**Edited**
I just verified that the code given by commentor does not work sadly. As an example, try this:

```
try{
        String urlStr = "http://www.yr.no/place/Norway/Nordland/Moskenes/Å/data.html";
        URL u=new URL(urlStr);
        URI uri = new URI(u.getProtocol(),
                    u.getUserInfo(), u.getHost(), u.getPort(),
                    u.getPath(), u.getQuery(),
                    null); // removing ref

        URL urlObj = uri.toURL();
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.connect();

        for (int i=0;i<connection.getHeaderFields().size();i++)
            System.out.println(connection.getHeaderFieldKey(i)+": "+connection.getHeaderField(i));
        System.exit(0);
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();};
```

Will yield a 404 error - strangely enough the encoded part does also not work.

Comment: I have updated my answer to limit the resulting URL to ASCII only (other characters are encoded). I believe this is the result that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a URL that is a valid URI (RFC 2396 compliant) you can create one like this in Java

```
    String urlString = "http://www.example.com/u/håkon-hellström/";

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(),url.getAuthority(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
    url = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
```

That being said all three sample strings you provided are RFC 2396 compliant and do not need to be encoded. I am assuming the spaces in the authority part of the URLs you provided are typos.

***EDIT:***

I updated the code block above. By using [`URI.toASCIIString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#toASCIIString%28%29) you can limit the resulting URI to only US-ASCII characters (other characters are encoded). The resulting string can then be used to create a new, valid URL.

`http://www.example.com/u/håkon-hellström/`

changes to

`http://www.example.com/u/h%C3%A5kon-hellstr%C3%B6m/`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The spaces are due to stackoverflow max-2-links policy for newcomers.

The problem is; the code you write here, is the same I have writen. However it does not work. Also, you will see all modern browsers change the URLs they send to the server to the hex'ed counter-parts.

Whether or not its RFC 2396 compliant or not I cannot say, but it definatly does not work.

Even Firefox translates "http://www.yr.no/place/Norway/Nordland/Moskenes/Å/data.html" into "http://www.yr.no/place/Norway/Nordland/Moskenes/%C3%85/data.html"

Comment: I updated my answer to use `URI.toASCIIString()` this should encode non-ASCII characters and give you the desired result.

Comment: Thank you sir, you are my hero :-)